# Does APNS cert need to be the same apple developer account as the app signing cert?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing a platform that supports multiple different iOS mobile apps running off the same backend (Firebase backend, Flutter frontend).

In some cases the Apple Developer account that the app is published will be different.

I've already set up a push notification certificate under one Apple Developer account.

My question is:

**Will push notifications work if the certificate that signs the app for release is from a different Apple developer account to the APNS certificate?**

Comment: The apns certificate must match the signing certificate, yes. If they are different, push notifications will not work.